# how do i save three inputs to a file with same name as the user?

Tags: bash, shell-script

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                     
while :                                                                         
        do                                                                      
        echo "Please enter your tittle:"                                        
        read TITTLE                                                             
        echo "Please enter your surname:"                                       
        read SURNAME                                                            
        echo "Please enter your ID No."                                         
        read ID                                                                 

        if [ "$TITTLE" = "" ] || [ "${TITTLE//[!0-9]}" != "" ];                 
        then                                                                    
        echo "Enter your valid tittle without special characters."              
        echo "Please try again."                                                
        continue                                                                  
        fi                                                                      

        if [ "$SURNAME" = "" ] || [ "${SURNAME//[!0-9]}" != "" ];               
        then                                                                    
        echo "Enter your valid surname without special characters."             
        echo "Please try again."                                                
        continue                                                                  
        fi                                                                      

        if [ "$ID" = "" ] || [ "${ID//[0-9]}" != "" ];                          
        then                                                                    
        echo "Enter your valid ID No. without special characters."              
        echo "Please try again"

        else                                                                    
        echo "Thank you" $TITTLE $SURNAME                                       
        break                                                                   
fi                                                                              
done
```

Comment: You will have to be more specific to describe, what you want to achieve. Is it possible that you want just this `echo $TITTLE > $USER; echo $SURNAME >> $USER; echo $ID >> $USER`?

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/572098/116858

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumption: `$SURNAME` is the user name

To write the content of `$TITTLE`, `$SURNAME` and  `$ID` to a file named after the content of `$SURNAME`, you could modify your code as follows:

```
...
    else
    echo "Thank you $TITTLE $SURNAME, your information will be stored in \"$SURNAME.txt\""
    echo -e "$TITTLE\n$SURNAME\n$ID" > "$SURNAME.txt"
    break
...
```

whereby -e allows echo to recognize `\n` as 'newline'.

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote in my answer to the related question "[Script that validates 3 inputs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/572098/116858)", the output of the script can be redirected by

```
$ ./script.sh >"$USER.txt"
```

where `$USER` will be replaced by your username (this variable, as well as `$LOGNAME`, is usually set to your username by the shell or system).

If you want to use the surname read by the script, then change the line

```bash
echo "Thank you" $TITTLE $SURNAME
```

into

```bash
echo "Thank you $TITTLE $SURNAME" >"$SURNAME.txt"
```

This would redirect the result of the `echo` to a file whose name is given by whatever the user entered for the surname, with `.txt` added to the end of the filename (this is optional, obviously).  Note that no check is made of whether this overwrites an existing file.

To also output this to the terminal, duplicate the data with `tee`:

```bash
echo "Thank you $TITTLE $SURNAME" | tee "$SURNAME.txt"
```

To output all three bits of data to the file, use, for example,

```bash
{
    printf 'ID = %s\n' "$ID"
    printf 'surname = %s\n' "$SURNAME"
    printf 'title = %s\s' "$TITTLE"
} >"$SURNAME.txt"
```

Grouping a set of commands inside curly braces like this allows you to redirect all output from the group in a single redirection.

See "[Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803)" for why I tend to use `printf` rather than `echo` when printing variable strings.